# ExtJS HTMLEditor paste behavior on IE/Edge

Tags: extjs, html-editor

I'm using HTML editor component and noticed a strange behavior on IE and EDGE.

When you paste some content from the notepad with blank lines, i.e:

```
Some line 1

Some line 2
```

Both browsers will ignone the blank line, i.e:

```
Some line 1
Some line 2
```

And when I paste on Firefox and Chrome, the browser transcribes everything:

```
Some line 1

Some line 2
```

Another thing about it is the html tags used in this, IE: will use **p** tags and the others will use **div** tags to enclosure all the line contents;

I don't believe this is necessary but [the code I'm using is equal at the docs of 6.5 even with the demo from docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor.html), I'll get the same behaviour.

Someone has a explanation for this happen or some workaround? I don't get if the blame is with the insertAtCursor or is a deep inside problem of the core but any help will be useful;